# How to smooth the vertical viewpager in android

Tags: android-viewpager, vertical-scrolling, vertical-scroll

Im creating one application, so i used vertical viewpager, viewpager working fine but it is not scrolling smoothly, it is sticking sometimes while swipe. here is my code, can anyone help me.thanks in advance.

```
 public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {
public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // The majority of the magic happens here
    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
    // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}


private static class VerticalPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {
    private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.95f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {


        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);


        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]

            view.setAlpha(1);
            //view.setTranslationX(1);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);
            view.setTranslationX(-1 * view.getWidth() * position);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            view.setTranslationX(-1 * view.getWidth() * position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else {
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }

    }
}

private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev);
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}
```

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar Have you found any solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

yes, all you need to do is ad this line to the view pager class:

```
@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with vertical `viewpager`. Finally, I got solution by just adding this attribute:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

in `viewpager` adapter's item view. So add it in on views (i.e `imageview` and `textview` depends on your layout) which **don't** have any `onClick` function with it.